# parsing mySQL code using regexp in python

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am trying to parse a bunch of SQL scripts to find out all the table they read from and write to.

So far I load the file, split it into the queries, and managed to parse a few things.

```
createproc = re.compile(r"""\s*create procedure (?P<procedurename>[a-zA-Z_0-9.]+)\s*""")
droptable = re.compile(r"""\s*drop table (if exists)* (?P<tablename>[a-zA-Z_0-9.]+)\s*""")
createtable = re.compile(r"""\s*create table (if not exists)* (?P<tablename>[a-zA-Z_0-9.]+)\s*""")
createindex = re.compile(r"""\s*create index [a-zA-Z_0-9. ]*on (?P<tablename>[a-zA-Z_0-9.]+)\s*""")
altertable = re.compile(r"""\s*alter table (?P<tablename>[a-zA-Z_0-9.]+)\s*""")
inserttable = re.compile(r"""\s*insert into (?P<tablename>[a-zA-Z_0-9.]+)\s*""")
updatetable = re.compile(r"""\s*update (?P<tablename>.*?)\s* set""")
deletetable = re.compile(r"""delete.*from[\r\n\s]*(?P<tablename>.*?)[\r\n\s]+""")
```

While I am sure all those regexps are not as good as they could be, especially the last one is causing me headaches.
I have a test string:

```
teststring = 'delete from my_db.my_table \r\n where\r\n(my_column >= 5/2 or my_column is null);'
```

And try to parse it:

```
match =deletetable.search(teststring,re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
if match:
    print(match.group("tablename"))
```

And I come up empty. I tried a couple of things but so far nothing helped.

The SQL scripts unfortunately are very inconsistent regarding linebreaks, whitespaces and indentation, so I have to consider all eventualities

Comment: Why not explore [Antlr](http://www.antlr3.org/api/Python/index.html). Better way to parse [SQL statements](http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/1347528470063/MySQL.g).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pass `flags` to `search` you need to supply them in the `compile` call. The `search` method of regex objects expect a starting position as the second argument instead of the flags.

```
import re
deletetable = re.compile(r'delete(?:\s+\w+)*?\s+from\s+(?P<tablename>[\w.]+)', 
           re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
teststring = 'delete from my_db.my_table \r\n where\r\n(my_column >= 5/2 or my_column is null);'
match =deletetable.search(teststring)
if match:
    print(match.group("tablename"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Marked as answer because it provided the most information (the other two answers work too)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in the usage of `re.MULTILINE` and `re.DOTALL`. I tried your test without them and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

this work :

```
deletetable2 = re.compile(r"""delete\s*from\s*(?P<tablename>\S*?)\s+.*""")
teststring = 'delete from my_db.my_table \r\n where\r\n(my_column >= 5/2 or my_column is null);'
print deletetable2.search(teststring).groups() # ('my_db.my_table',)
print deletetable2.search(teststring).group("tablename") # my_db.my_table
```

i think you have to simplify your expresion and finish by a dot and not specify the flags